# Does there exist a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\neq 0$

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$, such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})=0\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}{n}=0$$
but
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\neq 0 \ ?$$

Comment: Ted Shifrin [outlined a solution in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22216681#22216681).

Comment: There are two different readings of $\lim a_n\neq 0$. One is that the limit exists and is not zero, in which case, it is easily not possible, by my comment above. If it can mean that $\lim a_n$ does not exist, it might be possible to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$ means that $a_n$ converges to $a \neq 0$, it does not. Since is quite standard to prove that if $a_n \to a$ then 
$$
\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \to a
$$
Thus, supposing that $a_n \to a \neq 0$, then 
$$
\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \to a \neq 0
$$

Comment: But what if $a_n$ doesn't converge?

Comment: Did you confuse converse and contrapositive?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right ! editing !!

Comment: @ZachStone No, the question is confused. Does $\lim a_n\neq 0$ mean that the limit exists and is not zero, or does it mean that the limit might not exist, but if it does, it is not zero.

Comment: I understand. Your argument makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a sequence satisfying the first two hypotheses and $\lim a_n $ failing to exist: Let $T_n$ be the finite sequence

$$\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \dots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1, \frac{n-1}{n}, \dots , \frac{2}{n}, \frac{1}{n}.$$

Let $Z_n$ be the finite sequence of $2^n$ zeros. Then form the sequence

$$T_1\, Z_1 \,T_2\, Z_2 \,\dots \, T_n\, Z_n\, \dots,$$

meaning the finite sequence $T_1,$ followed by the finite sequence $Z_1,$ etc.